# Disable button in one controller from another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

Consider I have two controllers Ctrl1 and Ctrl2. On clicking a button in Ctrl1, the button in Ctrl2 should be disabled.

Any sample code for this??

Comment: both controllers are active at the same time?

Comment: use service for sharing data

Comment: Yes, use either service or rootScope to handle this.

Comment: SERVICE, ROOTSCOPE

Comment: if both controllers are on same template and ctrl2 is inside ctrl2 then you can use $parent to access ctrl1 scope in ctrl2

Comment: Please see my full answer with example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without $rootScope :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Controller2($scope, ButtonService) {
  $scope.object = ButtonService.getValue();
};

function Controller1($scope, ButtonService) {

  $scope.changeValue = function() {
    ButtonService.getValue(true);
  };

};

myApp.factory('ButtonService', function() {
  var obj = {}
  return {

    getValue: function(update) {
      var defaultValue = false;

      if (typeof(update) === 'undefined') {
        obj.val = defaultValue;
      } else {
        obj.val = update;
      }
      return obj;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <button ng-click="changeValue()">Click to change Value</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <button ng-disabled="object.val">{{!object.val ? 'Enabled Button' : 'Disabled Button'}}</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

**With $rootScope :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('myService', function($rootScope) {
  var self = this,
    disabledButton = false;

  this.setDisabledButton = function() {
    // Change here if you want to toggle on click
    if (!disabledButton) {
      disabledButton = true;
      $rootScope.$broadcast("btnDisabled", disabledButton);
    } else {
      return;
    }

  }

  this.getDisabledButton = function() {
    return disabledButton;
  }
});

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.disabledControllerButton = function() {
    myService.setDisabledButton();
  }
});

myApp.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.$on('btnDisabled', function(event, param) {
    $scope.Ctrl1ButtonClicked = param;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <button ng-click="disabledControllerButton()">
    Click to Change
  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="main" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <button ng-disabled="Ctrl1ButtonClicked">
    {{Ctrl1ButtonClicked ? 'Disabled ' : 'Enabled '}} Button
  </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Kindly check this snippet. It might help you out.

Comment: Could you help me the same without using rootscope

Comment: Let me try. Any issues with $rootscope?

Comment: No issues. I just wanted to know how to do the same without rootscope

Comment: Answer Updated. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1. Angular events: use a the `$broadcast` or `$emit` from the relevant controller(Ctrl1) to notify the brother controller (Ctrl2), at the reciveing controller use $on to listen the event see [Angular Events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).
2. Second option: Use a parent scope for both controller and save the state of the button on it - Lets say you have CtrlP has the parent you set on the `$scope` of CtrlP the property `$scope.isButton2Disabled` to be false. then on the child controller Ctrl1 on the click handler you add the following line `$scope.$parent.isButton2Disabled = true;` on the view of Ctrl2 you add `ng-disabled="isButton2Disabled"` See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kR859/128/)
3. Last one and IMO the worst way, just use `$rootScope` and set `$rootScope.isButton2Disabled = false;` when you're init the app, then when clicking on the button in Ctrl1 add the following code in the click handler: `$rootScope.isButton2Disabled = true;` all you need now is to do the same on #2 add `ng-disabled="isButton2Disabled"` to the button you want to disable.

For further reading: [Sharing data with angular](http://www.ramandv.com/blog/angular-js-sharing-data/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by the following implementation.

```
1.Module.service() 
2.Module.factory() 
3.Module.provider()
4.Module.value()
5.using $parent in HTML code
6.using $parent in child controller
7.using controller inheritance
8.Holding the shared data in the root scope
9.Using $emit,$broadcast
```